Jest Test suite failed to run - TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined, but the reducer is not even being called according to console.log?
Problem
All 24 of my existing jest test suites failed saying
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined


right after I made this commit in my history:

My Investigation Attempts and Questions

When I yarn start my project, the code runs fine. No compilation errors.
Since the call stack mentioned my main reducer, I tried to add a console.log(state) in it to see if my state is really undefined. But my console.log is not being printed out in yarn test. How can it not console.log if it's reached in the test call stack and breaking all my 24 test suites (reducer-related or not)? 

